# Riesz measure of a subharmonic function and that of its regularization

Tags: real-analysis, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Suppose $u$ is a subharmonic function on a bounded open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m\geq2$). Let $u_n$  be a sequence of smooth subharmonic functions that decreases pointwise to  $u$ (obtained by convolution with a smoothing test function).
Suppose $\mu$ is the Riesz measure associated to $u$ and $\mu_n$ the Riesz measure associated to $u_n$. We know that since $u_n$ is smooth, $\mu_n=\Delta u_n d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the $m-$ dimensional Lebesgue measure. I have two question:
We know that for any any smooth function $\phi$ with compact support in $V$ (i.e. $\phi\in C^\infty_0(V)$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_V\phi(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_V\phi(x)d\mu(x)?$$

My question is: Can we say that for any open set $W$ in $V$ the above equation holds? i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_W\phi(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_W\phi(x)d\mu(x)?$$

Comment: I don’t know the definition of Riesz measure of a subharmonic function. If it agrees with the distributional laplacian, then 1 just says that the distributional laplacian of $u_n$ converges to the distributional laplacian of $u$, which follows from the distributional convergence of $u_n$ to $u$. I am not quite sure about the point 2 though

Comment: For the distributional convergence of $u_n$ to $u$ you have to use how the $u_n$ are defined, clearly

Comment: Thanks. Do you some construction of $u_n$ for which the answer to the question is yes?

Comment: Do you mean my last comment? The standard regularization of u converges distributionally to u itself for any distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I haven’t studied Riesz measures for subharmonic functions, so my answer could not be 100% appropriate or canonical.

Concerning your question, the answer is no. The idea is that you are basically multiplying $\phi$ by a characteristic function, so the function you test $\mu_n$ against is not continuous. That is in general a problem for converging measures.

If you take a general succession of Radon measures $\mu_n$ which converges (in measure) to $\mu$, the thesis is not true. For instance, take a radial $\phi$, $\mu$ to be the dirac delta in the origin, $\mu_n$ a standard regularization of it (so, basically, just the standard mollifier), $V=B_1(0)$ and $W=V\cap\{x_1>0\}$. We have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_W\phi(x)d\mu_n(x)=1/2 \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_V\phi(x)d\mu_n(x)=1/2\int_V\phi(x)d\mu(x),$$

which is in general nonzero, while

$$\int_W\phi(x)d\mu(x)=0.$$

You can realize the measures above with subharmonic functions taking $u=-\Gamma$ and $u_n$ a standard regularization of $u$, where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of the Laplace operator in $\mathbb R^m$, s.t. $\Delta\Gamma=-\delta$ distributionally.

My only doubt is that I don’t know if that $u$ is regular enough for your setting, or it doesn’t count as it is unbounded. If not ok, you could take instead $u=\max(-\Gamma,-c)$ (with $c>0$ large enough for $u$ not to be constant on $V$), that is subharmonic, bounded, and the Laplacian is supported on a spherical surface inside $V$ that is basically the set of points where the gradient of $u$ is discontinuous. Finally, taking $W$ as the complement of that surface should do an analogous trick.